# Does Facebook notify a user when their picture is removed per privacy-violation request?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-privacy, facebook-photos

I found a few pictures of my kids on Facebook that I would like to file a [child privacy take-down request](https://www.facebook.com/help/428478523862899). What happens when Facebook actually removes the pictures... is the picture-poster notified?

In my social context, it's going to be quite obvious that I filed for a take down request. I'm hoping that the user forgets about the photo and it silently disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the user will be notified. Also user's account will not work like normal (he will be able to navigate a limited number of Facebook pages) for 12-24 hrs. But he will not get to know who marked the image as spam. (As they are your kids, he might guess it.)

The picture will be deleted by Facebook from his timeline or the place where you have marked it as spam, but you know once some picture is uploaded to the internet, it remains on the internet. (Facebook will also keep it in their database but will not be visible to anyone.)

Comment: Do you have any supporting references or just former experience?

Comment: I will check that. But this reply was from my personal experience... We in college use to report spam each other (friends) for fun...

Answer (score 1):

If you have reported through **Report Photo** (over the photo or video and click Options in the bottom-right corner), then picture poster will get notified. If you have reported it under **Intellectual Property**, then picture poster might not get any notification.